# Can I run aluminum backed organic brake pads with Elixir Avid 5 hydraulic system?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, brake-pads

The old pads were steel.  I bought the aluminum thinking they would disperse heat better but if it's going to cause a problem with the braking system I'll go back to steel at less than half the price.

Comment: I am not sure if the Elixir is of the type of caliper that contains a magnet to position the pads? If it is, my guess is aluminum pads are not compatible.

Comment: How are you planning on fitting pads that don't say they're compatible on the packet?

Comment: I don't know about magnets, but if your elixir 5 have a mounting bolt to keep them in place, then that's probably enough. I think what Alex means is if they say they're compatible on the packet then they must be compatible, but I detect a hint of sarcasm!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are aluminum backed organic brake pads available for the Elixir series brakes.

The SRAM part number is `11.5015.040.020` with the description `[Disc Brake Pads Organic/Aluminum - Elixir 20 sets]`, according to the [2014 SRAM Spare Parts Catalog](https://sram-cdn-pull-zone-gsdesign.netdna-ssl.com/cdn/farfuture/VZCoZNqKj08r2MTogGsk9etnNLryzw9HW2bIP7fnfgU/mtime:1379456585/sites/default/files/techdocs/2014_avid_spc_rev_a.pdf).